# Matching Array value with cell value not working

Tags: arrays, vba

I was on this problem for 2 hours now, I guess I am just missing something, maybe someone can help me figure it out. Thanks

Part of user identification process, I am trying to match the array value with the cell value to the user can access their privileges. The problem is it doesn't return it as true despite the value being the same.

In this example, note these infos;

- ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(DATASheet).Cells(1, 52).value = "16589455"
- when I debug.print the value for UserId(1) and CurrentUser which equal to  "16589455", you can notice there is a space in the current user value (see screenshot), could that be the problem? any solution?

```
    Sub ClientSegregation()
    Call Globalvariables
    
    Dim UserID
        UserID = Array("14526398", "16589455", "16598785", "12658744", "12658746", "15987456", "14896523", "16589564", "13658794", "18991548", "11122233")
    
    
    Dim ws, wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim wbk2, wbk1 As Workbook
    Dim lastRow, LastColumn As Long
    Dim WS_Count, i As Integer
    Dim cel, CellOfValue As Range
    
    
    'Dynamic references
    BackwardPath = Left(ThisWorkbook.Path, InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Path, "\") - 1)
    inputpath = BackwardPath & "\Models_Inputs"
    LastColumn = Cells(88, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    
    fileStr = inputpath & "\Database.xlsx"
    Set wbk1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set wbk2 = Workbooks.Open(fileStr)
    
    CurrentUser  = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(DATASheet).Cells(1, 52).value
    
    For i = 0 To UBound(UserID)
        If UserID(i) = CurrentUser Then
    
                        MsgBox "OK"
        End If
    Next i
    
    End Sub
```

[image: Debug.Print]

Comment: The two variables are likely to be of different types. First off, [don't declare multiple variables that way](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dim/#How_to_Use_Dim_with_Multiple_Variables). Second, even with a value being `Variant`, VBA will assume the type of that variable. So you may be comparing an integer with a string (this is a good guess because you see a space before the user ID). So force each value into the same type (see `CStr` and `CLng`). If you're using a `String` comparison, remember to use `Trim`.

Comment: @PeterT Thanks for the quick reply, used CStr and worked. I guess the variables types were different as you mentioned.